# Zend Stack Trace not showing up due to fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have a Zend 1.11 application that is giving me a similar fatal error when any error exists

The Error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ' in C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php:277 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('tcp://localhost...') 
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect()
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Mail\Transport\Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail() 
#3 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail)) 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\application\modules\default\controllers\ErrorController.php(153): Zend_Mail->send() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\application\modules\default\controllers\ErrorController.php(66): Default_ErrorController->SendMail('Application err...', 'An error oc...') 
#6 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): Default_ErrorController->errorAction() 
#7 C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Controller\Disp in C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

This is preventing the correct stack trace from showing up (i.e this error came from an intentional misnaming of the database which would normally throw an unknow DB exception) and there is'nt really anything to do with mail on this PHP application. Any advice would help. Thanks

Comment: Hmm. That error message is a stack trace. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You can also catch the exception by wrapping the calling code in a try -catch block

Comment: I'm guessing that the exception is being handled by Zend, and the error handler is trying to e-mail the error to you. However, it can't, so it spits that error out to you rather than the one you want.

Comment: @christopher_b Sorry its throwing this error for any and all errors. i generated this one by purposefully naming my DB incorrectly which would normally throw me the exception Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'xxxxxx'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On reviewing your callstack, it's the ErrorController within your application which is throwing the error.

I would guess it's trying to e-mail you the error details, rather than throwing the exception.

This obviously needs to be fixed, but to see your error now try adding this into your application.ini

```
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
phpSettings.display_startup_errors  = 1
phpSettings.display_errors          = 1
phpSettings.error_reporting         = "8191"
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = true
```

This will throw any errors to screen, rather than trying to handle them.

Comment: Same error. This is from an svn repo and that repo usually mails out server/php errors to a group so maybe that could be causing the problem ?

Comment: Have a look at the Default_ErrorController::SendMail method. This is being triggered when the exception is handled. It's trying to mail somebody, and can't!

Comment: Yep that did it, I commented out the sendMail function (just for my local test purposes) and it worked thanks so much!